# Replaying transactions after a deadlock in a Session-Per-Request web environment

Tags: nhibernate, deadlock

I would like to be able to rerun transactions if a deadlock occurs. In [Ayende's blog post](http://ayende.com/blog/4159/your-queries-are-going-to-fail-in-production) he mentions that you need to throw away the whole NHibernate session and start again.

Restarting the session is relatively straightforward in a Windows app, but how would you do this in a web app when using the Session-Per-Request module? The session is opened and closed inside an IHttpModule. The only way I can think of is to reissue the http post somehow. This would be fiddly, and could also end up re-executing other transactions that had already been committed successfully (as we have multiple transactions per Session).

Comment: The other way is to figure out why the deadlocks are occurring in the first place.  Look at deadlock graphs.  Maybe fix the deadlock by making program changes or adding an index.

Comment: Yes that's what everyone says, but it's a bit too late if the deadlock has already occurred.

Comment: A bit too late?  That's the only time you can fix deadlocks is after they happen.  If you are running mssql set up a trace to capture deadlock events including deadlock graphs.  You will learn a lot by looking at what two statements are deadlocking.  I've ran into this situation numerous times.

Comment: I mean if the deadlock has occurred it's too late to start figuring out why it occurred - it already happened and the user got an error. I know perfectly well how to profile and repair systems that are deadlocking frequently - what I am looking for is a generic way to rerun transactions that will cater for situations where I have not yet had a chance to profile and repair the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose the ISessionFactory somehow so you can use it to create a new ISession when needed. A quick solution would be to set a static property in global.asax.

Comment: Yes I know how to create a new session, the question is how to architect a solution to rerun the failed transaction.

Comment: At what point do you rerun the transaction? In each controller's code? In an Http Module?

Comment: I would encapsulate the operation in its own class (command pattern) and re-run the transaction in the controller using a new session. However, my experience is that user interaction is typically needed when a transaction fails. I would also devote more effort to preventing deadlocks (rare in my experience) than attempting to automatically re-try.